# Using sys.dm_os_performance_counters and DIFF to display logins per second

Tags: sql-server-2005, performance, t-sql, monitoring

### PROBLEM

Running my script below i can see the number of logins as an accumulated number to my instance:

```
SELECT cntr_value AS [LoginsPerSec]
    FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
    WHERE 
    object_name = 'SQLServer:General Statistics'
    AND counter_name = 'Logins/sec'
```

Running it again 1 second later returns an increased value.

The difference between the two appears to indicate the increased number of logins within that period of time (second) between the two executions.

### QUESTION1

How do I execute this twice within the same script to retrun the DIFF between the two values ?

Simply need the DIFF value only as the result therefore allowing me to plot the value on a live chart.

Currently doing this for active connections using:

```
SELECT count(dbid) as NoOfConnections
FROM sys.sysprocesses
WHERE dbid = 5
GROUP BY dbid
```

### QUESTION2

Can you recommend any other performance counters visable via sys.dm_os_performance_counters that would allow me to monitor where my CPU resource is being used by SQL server ?

Thanks for any help

Scott

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, think this should work.

```
DECLARE @CurrentLoginUser int
DECLARE @CurrentLoginUser1 int


SET @CurrentLoginUser = (SELECT cntr_value AS [LoginsPerSec] FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters WHERE object_name = 'SQLServer:General Statistics' AND counter_name = 'Logins/sec')
WAITFOR DELAY '000:00:01'
SET @CurrentLoginUser1 = (SELECT cntr_value AS [LoginsPerSec] FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters WHERE object_name = 'SQLServer:General Statistics' AND counter_name = 'Logins/sec')

SELECT @CurrentLoginUser1 - @CurrentLoginUser
```

Comment: For future compatibility (at least in this specific case), only filter `sys.dm_os_performance_counters` by `counter_name`. In 2008 R2 where I first tried this code, the `object_name` column contains the server instance name, and it returned nothing.